# How to reduce demand the writing?

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive, persistence

I use a live USB stick with persistence, but what I realize is that the USB Stick does not meet the writing demand.
When I open two web pages at the same time, for example, it's like I'm browsing on a 0.1 Mbps network. Everything is very limited. When I try to open some application while doing this, it takes a long time to load. I realize this because my USB Stick has a LED that indicates the activity, And I can only do most things when it stops blinking, and if I remove it while using Live USB, the internet returns to normal ...

Is there any way to reduce demand the writing/reading? I've already tried to disable the Chrome cache and it did not work. Because I definitely do not want to buy an external hard drive.

Thank you very much
(Sorry for the errors in the calligraphy, I used the [Google Translator](https://translate.google.com))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody answered, but I discovered a stupidly easy way, and I will share it, it can serve for someone...
All I did was to open the anonymous navigation, after that I did not have any more problems with the internet, now I can put 5 videos to run at the same time without over loading the USB Stick. I just do not understand why the cache deactivation did not solve.
The rest, such as opening programs, will have a certain limitation, but there should be no way to improve it, other than using a lightweight distro, or use a USB Stick 3.0, which usually has a writing rate above 5Mb/s, since almost all USB Stick to port 2.0, has only this, remember to see benchmark tests to certify before buying a.